# Compare XPath list to find the closest to another node?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, closest, prediction

I have the following node

```
"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[7]/p[1]/#text[1]"
```

How can I figure out that the last one of these is the closest one?

```
"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/img[1]"
"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/a[1]/img[1]"
"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/a[2]/img[1]"
"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[5]/img[1]"
"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/img[1]"
```

It won't always be necessarily the last one.

Here's how I got there:

```
protected string GuessThumbnail(HtmlDocument document)
{
    HtmlNode root = document.DocumentNode;
    IEnumerable<string> result = new List<string>();

    HtmlNode description = root.SelectSingleNode(DescriptionPredictiveXPath);
    if (description != null) // in this case, we predict relevant images are the ones closest to the description text node.
    {
        HtmlNode node = description.ParentNode;
        while (node != null)
        {
            string path = string.Concat(node.XPath, ImageXPath);
            node = node.ParentNode;
            IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes = root.SelectNodesOrEmpty(path);

            // find the image tag that's closest to the text node.
            if (nodes.Any())
            {
                var xpaths = nodes.Select(n => n.XPath);
                xpaths.ToList();

                // return closest
            }
        }
    }
    // figure some other way to do it

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean closest by how near it is within the document structure to the target element?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I want somehow to figure out `div[7]` is closer to `div[5]` than to `div[4]`, and if there are more than one `div[5]` then inspect the next level, etc. Until I find the closest element.

Comment: Is your code using the Html Agility Pack from CodePlex?

Comment: Also, will the elements you need to sort between always have the same element type at the same level, i.e. div to div, etc.? The problem is that you cannot determine nearness by the indexers if they are not and that eliminates simply being able to compare the xpaths. If they are dissimilar nodes, then your only way to diferentiate is to traverse the tree and record a distance metric for each discovered node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it like this:

```
    protected string GuessThumbnail(HtmlDocument document)
    {
        HtmlNode root = document.DocumentNode;
        HtmlNode description = root.SelectSingleNode(DescriptionPredictiveXPath);

        if (description != null)
        {
            // in this case, we predict relevant images are the ones closest to the description text node.
            HtmlNode parent = description.ParentNode;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                string path = string.Concat(parent.XPath, ImageXPath);
                IList<HtmlNode> images = root.SelectNodesOrEmpty(path).ToList();

                // find the image tag that's closest to the text node.
                if (images.Any())
                {
                    HtmlNode descriptionOutermost = description.ParentNodeUntil(parent); // get the first child towards the description from the parent node.
                    int descriptionIndex = descriptionOutermost.GetIndex(); // get the index of the description's outermost element.

                    HtmlNode closestToDescription = null;
                    int distanceToDescription = int.MaxValue;

                    foreach (HtmlNode image in images)
                    {
                        int index = image.ParentNodeUntil(parent).GetIndex(); // get the index of the image's outermost element.
                        if (index > descriptionIndex)
                        {
                            index *= -1;
                        }
                        int distance = descriptionIndex - index;
                        if (distance < distanceToDescription)
                        {
                            closestToDescription = image;
                            distanceToDescription = distance;
                        }
                    }
                    if (closestToDescription != null)
                    {
                        string source = closestToDescription.Attributes["src"].Value;
                        return source;
                    }
                }

                parent = parent.ParentNode;
            }
        }
        // figure some other way to do it

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


public static HtmlNode ParentNodeUntil(this HtmlNode node, HtmlNode parent)
{
    while (node.ParentNode != parent)
    {
        node = node.ParentNode;
    }
    return node;
}
public static int GetIndex(this HtmlNode node)
{
    return node.ParentNode.ChildNodes.IndexOf(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning "position in whole tree in depth-first order" to each node. This way comparing 2 nodes will be very simple.

If you can attach arbitrary data to your nodes - add it directly. Otherwise have dictionary of all nodes to position map.

Note that depending on how many times you need to do this comparison this approach may be to slow for you, but it should be easy to implement and measure it it meats your requirements.